# Using LAG to get the previous non-identical value while not considering certain columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

This may be an extension to the question
[Using LAG function to obtain value that is not necessarily in the previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199989/using-lag-function-to-obtain-value-that-is-not-necessarily-in-the-previous-row?rq=3)

I have a table `my_table` that I would like to create a new column `previous_order_date` is based on the *episode_id, file_id, and order_date.* There is another column `offer_id` that I don't want to consider for the `previous_order_date` calculation

| episode_id | file_id | offer_id | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 3000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 4000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 12-OCT-20 |

Query:

```
create table my_table
(episode_id number,
  file_id number,
  offer_id number,
  order_date date
);

insert all
 into my_table values (1234,3000,700, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (1234,3000,800, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (1234,3000,900, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (1234,3000,800, to_date('2020/10/11','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (1234,3000,900, to_date('2020/10/11','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (1234,4000,700, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (1234,4000,800, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (1234,4000,700, to_date('2020/10/11','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,3000,700, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,3000,800, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,3000,900, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,3000,800, to_date('2020/10/11','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,3000,900, to_date('2020/10/11','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,4000,700, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,4000,800, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,5000,700, to_date('2020/10/10','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,5000,700, to_date('2020/10/11','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,4000,700, to_date('2020/10/11','YYYY/MM/DD'))
 into my_table values (4321,3000,700, to_date('2020/10/12','YYYY/MM/DD'))
```

I want to use LAG to get the previous order_date based on partitioned by episode_id and file_id, that is I don't want to get the previous row order_date if it's the same with a different offer_id.

I'm trying to get the output to be like this:

| episode_id | file_id | offer_id | order_date | previous_order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 3000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 1234 | 4000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 4000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 12-OCT-20 | 11-OCT-20 |

but I've tried running this query

```
select episode_id
       ,file_id
       ,offer_id
      ,order_date
      ,lag(order_date) over(partition by episode_id, file_id order by order_date) as previous_order_date
from my_table
```

however that produces this table

| episode_id | file_id | offer_id | order_date | previous_order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 3000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 10-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 11-OCT-20 | 11-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 1234 | 4000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 10-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 4000 | 800 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 10-OCT-20 | null |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 11-OCT-20 | 10-OCT-20 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 12-OCT-20 | 11-OCT-20 |

which takes the previous row order_date regardless of offer_id. It is quite a big query to get to this point, and I need the offer_id column for further calculations since I'm joining other tables based on that column. So I was wondering since the real-world application has order_date down to the minute if there was a way to have LAG look at previous rows that were at least 1 minute older, similar to the INTERVAL function.

I have tried selecting the episode_id, file_id, and order_date in a CTE and using LAG there but this duplicated the rows, one row with the order_date as the previous_order_date, and one row with a null previous_order_date. The same occurred when I tried to use DENSE_RANK for some reason.

My DB version is 19c

Comment: It's not as pretty as `lag`, but would you consider a subquery like https://dbfiddle.uk/ufaGpQCr ? Or you could rewrite that as a `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to `PARTITION BY episode_id, file_id, offer_id` within the `LAG`:

```sql
select episode_id,
       file_id,
       offer_id,
       order_date,
       LAG(order_date) OVER(
         PARTITION BY episode_id, file_id, offer_id
         ORDER BY order_date
       ) AS previous_order_date
FROM   my_table
```

Or, maybe, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
select *
FROM   my_table
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY episode_id, file_id
  ORDER BY order_date DESC, offer_id DESC
  MEASURES
    current_row.offer_id AS offer_id,
    current_row.order_date AS order_date,
    prev_day.order_date AS previous_order_date
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
  PATTERN ( current_row {- same_day* -} prev_day? )
  DEFINE
    same_day AS TRUNC(current_row.order_date) = TRUNC(same_day.order_date)
)
ORDER BY episode_id, file_id, order_date, offer_id
```

Which, for your sample data, output:

| EPISODE_ID | FILE_ID | OFFER_ID | ORDER_DATE | PREVIOUS_ORDER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 3000 | 700 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 1234 | 3000 | 800 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 1234 | 3000 | 900 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 1234 | 4000 | 800 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 1234 | 4000 | 700 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 4321 | 3000 | 800 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 900 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 4321 | 4000 | 800 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 4321 | 5000 | 700 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 4321 | 4000 | 700 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 4321 | 3000 | 700 | 2020-10-12 00:00:00 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QC1bf-lY)